# how to add an event by touching in day view in calenderUI

Tags: ios, calendar

[image]i have a calenderUi.

[Github Link](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)

In this framework how to add a function call by touching on Hours Row?

How shoule I use this framework in landscape?

if you have worked or possess prior experience in similar framework, please give suggestions on how to achieve this?

NOW if i touched in 5hour row how recognize the Hour value and i have to redirect to another View..

Comment: Can you exactly show screen shot where you are trying to touch and which is the event you want to handle?

Comment: Now see my Question once...